# How to change logic from foreach loop to batch in Mule 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I am experimenting to convert a foreach logic that already works into batch job. In mule 4 it is quite simple, only in Mule 3 unfortunately not.

The idea of my experiment is that with the ids I got from a previous HTTP request call, to do new HTTP request call using the recieved id's quickly after each others. It could be 1000 ids (1000 requests) that need to be passed.

How could I do this? Is there a better way?

Below I added both logics;

##### Foreach version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration_Service"
        protocol="HTTPS" host="${service.host}"
        port="${service.port}"
        basePath="?$filter=id eq #[payload]" 
        doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" responseTimeout="${service.timeout}">
        <http:basic-authentication username="${service.user}" password="${service.password}" preemptive="true"/>
    </http:request-config>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <set-payload value="1234f15c-g4fb-511f-ba41-0ced971ec747,f6cb2052-3520-47c0-ba53-202029c8c5df,0ca68b3b-b2c0-4dba-a54a-2bbef4e8bcf2,12a8c48c-c221-4c10-82ab-c2222b5b2cac,3f394fda-d687-4d68-bb27-f532ca650803" doc:name="Incoming payload"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Fetch the id">
            <dw:set-variable variableName="id"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.value.id joinBy "," default ""]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-payload value="#[#[java.util.Arrays.asList(flowVars.id.split(','))]]" doc:name="Transform to array"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration_Service" path="/request/change/serviceRequest" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP Request Service">
                <http:request-builder>
                    <http:query-params expression="{&quot;?$filter&quot;: &quot;id eq #[payload]&quot;}"/>
                </http:request-builder>
            </http:request>
            <dw:transform-message doc:name="Append payload">
                <dw:set-variable variableName="outcome"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
flowVars.outcome ++ payload]]></dw:set-variable>
            </dw:transform-message>
        </foreach>
        </foreach>
</mule>
```

##### BATCH JOB version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd">
 <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration_Service"
        protocol="HTTPS" host="${service.host}"
        port="${service.port}"
        basePath="?$filter=id eq #[payload]" 
        doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" responseTimeout="${service.timeout}">
        <http:basic-authentication username="${service.user}" password="${service.password}" preemptive="true"/>
    </http:request-config>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    "@odata.context": "https://scrum-caller.com/repo/v1/inside#Changes",
    "value": [
        {
      "id": "8db55441-6255-4d24-8d39-658536985214",
      "number": "0w-30",
      "Desc": "maintain"
    },
    {
      "id": "11111111-6666-2222-3g3g-854712547412",
      "number": "5w-40",
      "Desc": "on prod"
    },
    {
      "id": "1ab32c5b-ffs3-3243-74fv-3376218042bb",
      "number": "5w-30",
      "Desc": "on test"
    }
    ]
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Fetch the id">
            <dw:set-variable variableName="id"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.value.id joinBy "," default ""]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-payload value="#[#[java.util.Arrays.asList(flowVars.id.split(','))]]" doc:name="Transform to array"/>
        <set-session-variable variableName="outcome" value="#[[]]" doc:name="Outcome var array"/>
        <batch:execute name="batch-job-flow" doc:name="Batch Execute"/>
        </foreach>
    <batch:job name="batch-job-flow">
        <batch:process-records>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step">
                <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration_Service" path="/request/change/serviceRequest" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP Request Service">
                    <http:request-builder>
                        <http:query-params expression="{&quot;?$filter&quot;: &quot;id eq #[payload]&quot;}"/>
                    </http:request-builder>
                </http:request>
                <dw:transform-message doc:name="Append payload">
                    <dw:set-variable variableName="outcome"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
flowVars.outcome ++ payload]]></dw:set-variable>
                </dw:transform-message>
            </batch:step>
            <batch:step name="Batch_Step2">
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Local\test" outputPattern="test.json" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:process-records>
    </batch:job>


</mule>
```

Comment: "only in Mule3 unfortunately not" you are not providing any details on what issues are you having, and why you are need to do a batch version if you already have a foreach version. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: Also, you are using `payload.value.id` but it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: @aled The reason I am looking into batch is; because I like to be prepared for the growth of the incoming payload in the future and besides the fact that foreach is running on single thread. So it might cause issue in the future. You're right about that the payload unclear, but hope it's in the right place now.

Comment: The sample code provided is not really consistent. Please review

Comment: @aled you mean the batch job? The idea is to convert the foreach loop into batch. This in case I will get large payload as array that foreach can not handle. So input will remain the same, but processing need to handle large payload.

Comment: What is the format of the output of the HTTP Request? JSON?

Comment: @aled, yes JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your batch version is incorrect conceptually. For example you can not add values to a flow or session variable in a batch. Note that Batch works with records and outside flows.

Additionally you can not control in which thread each record is going to be processed. That means that the output may be overwritten or corrupted if you try to write it to a file. You need to use an output that is able to receive data concurrently, like a database. Then you should be able to extract and combine the output into a JSON file.

Note that foreach will also work with any number of records. You may have other problems like performance because it is not concurrent in Mule 3, but it can be in Mule 4.

Unrelated, I don't understand the strange transformations to try to get a list of ids. It seems that the simple DataWeave expression `payload.value.*id` should be enough to extract that from the input, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I have tested the application with foreach containing 1000 records and the application gives no error but also no response (which mean is too much to handle)
If I Make the payload with 300 or 400 objects than it works just fine. 
The application also saves the last successful run timestamp and that will be used to query the data from last run.
This means that if the application does not run for 10 hours for any reason, we will lose a lot of data. No queue is the requirement.